# Is „sich von etw. unterhalten“ as correct as „sich über etw. unterhalten“?

Tags: preposition

In standard dictionaries the preposition collocated with ,,sich unterhalten'' is ,,über'', hence ,,sich unterhalten über etw.'' is definitely correct.

On the other hand, I am wondering whether ,,sich unterhalten von etw.'' could be a possible alternative, in analogy to the cases of ,,sprechen/reden'' :

von/über etw. sprechen

von/über etw. reden

Comment: No, this is no alternative. "sich unterhalten von" would be definitely wrong.

Answer (score 6):

No. It is *sich über etwas unterhalten*. Always. *von* is definitely wrong in this context.

Answer (score 2):

You can

- talk about something (*sich über etwas unterhalten*) or
- be entertained by something (*sich mit etwas unterhalten*
  or *sich von etwas/jemandem unterhalten lassen*)

where *unterhalten* has complete different meanings in those two cases.

Answer (score 1):

### Reden, sprechen

The verbs *reden* and *sprechen* can be used transitive and intransitive, but not reflexive:

- **intransitive** (without accusative object)

  > Jetzt rede ich!
  >   Jürgen redet mit Helga.
  >   Hans redet von dir, nicht von Julia.
  >   Anna redet nich gerne über ihre Eltern.

  (All Examples work also with *sprechen* instead of *reden*.)
- **transitive** (with accusative object)

  > Heinz spricht Deutsch.
  >   Du redest nur Müll.
- **reflexive** (with a reflexive pronoun, i.e. *mich/dich/sich/uns/euch*)

  > Wrong: <del>*Ich spreche mich ...*</del>

  There is just an idiom in which *reden* is used reflexive: »Er redet sich um Kopf und Kragen.« But this is an exception. Normally you don't use *reden* or *sprechen* reflexive.

---

### unterhalten

The Verb *unterhalten* has more than one meanings. Think of each meaning as a different word.

1. **jemanden unterhalten** = to entertain somebody

   > Die Akrobaten unterhielten das Publikum im Zirkuszelt.
   >   The acrobats entertained the audience in the circus tent.

   In this meaning *unterhalten* is used transitive (i.e. with an accusative object)
2. **sich mit jemandem unterhalten** = to talk with somebody

   > Jürgen unterhielt sich mit Helga über den gestrigen Vorfall.
   >   Jürgen talked with Helga about yesterday's incident.

   In this meaning *unterhalten* is always used reflexive (with a reflexive pronoun) and with a prepositional object (»mit« + dative object).
3. **sich unterhalten** = to be amused

   > Ich habe gestern ein Kabarett besucht, ich habe mich köstlich unterhalten.
   >   I visited a comedy show yesterday, I was very amused.

   In this meaning *unterhalten* is always used reflexive (with a reflexive pronoun) but without any other object.
4. **jemanden unterhalten** = to support a person (financially)

   > Kein Wunder, dass er mit dem Geld nicht auskommt. Herr Mayer unterhält gleich drei Geliebte.
   >   No wonder he does not manage with the money. Mr. Mayer has three lovers.

   In this meaning *unterhalten* is used transitive (i.e. with an accusative object)
5. **etwas unterhalten** = to maintain

   > Die Römer unterhielten enge Kontakte zu den Etruskern.
   >   The Romans maintained close contacts with the Etruscans.

   In this meaning *unterhalten* is used transitive (i.e. with an accusative object)

---

The meaning you had in mind with your question, is #2 in the list above. There are two patterns that you can use with this verb:

1. <*Person A*> **unterhält sich** mit <*Person B*>.
2. <*Person A*> **unterhält sich** mit <*Person B*> über <*Thema*>.

in (2) the parts »mit <*Person B*>« and »über <*Thema*>« are both prepositional objects. The Object starting with *mit* is mandatory, the Object starting with *über* is optional.